# convert binary tree to sum tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

[REFERENCE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-given-tree-to-sum-tree/)  I am copy pasting the problem and the solution that works in C, I am not able to get this working in Java. I understand primarily it is because in Java parameters are passed by value and that is causing problem to maintain state of "old_value". But I even tried changing it to a custom MyInt with set and get, still not able to get this working. So, probably I am missing something else too here. Kindly suggest.

> Given a Binary Tree where each node has positive and negative values.
>   Convert this to a tree where each node contains the sum of the left
>   and right sub trees in the original tree. The values of leaf nodes are
>   changed to 0.

For example, the following tree

```
              10
           /      \
         -2        6
       /   \      /  \ 
      8     -4    7    5
```

should be changed to

```
             20(4-2+12+6)
           /      \
      4(8-4)      12(7+5)
       /   \      /  \ 
      0      0    0    0
```

Code:

```
int toSumTree(struct node *node)
{
    // Base case
    if(node == NULL)
      return 0;


// Store the old value
int old_val = node->data;

// Recursively call for left and right subtrees and store the sum as
// new value of this node
node->data = toSumTree(node->left) + toSumTree(node->right);

// Return the sum of values of nodes in left and right subtrees and
// old_value of this node
return node->data + old_val;
```

}

Java Code:

```
public static int sumTree(Node node){
        if(node == null)
            return 0;
        MyInt old_value = new MyInt(node.data);
        node.data = sumTree(node.left) + sumTree(node.right);
        return node.data + old_value.getData();
    }
```

Comment: Since you didn't post your Java code - it's not easy to find your errors...

Comment: As long as you use `int`, the things are copied by value. OTOH `Integer` is immutable, so it does not matter if you pass it by value or by reference. If you pasted your Java code, we'd have better chances to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your C code is only passing things by value anyway (specifically it's passing pointers by value), so I can't see how that aspect of Java would break anything.

Comment: Aah .. I completely missed that. Then the current code should work as it is in Java ? I must be doing something stupid then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running wrong tests. Same code logic will work in Java as well as rightly pointed out in comments that pass by value does not make a difference because value is getting returned. The following is the working Java Code:

```
public static int sumTree(TreeNode node){
        if(node == null)
            return 0;
        int old_value = node.value;
        node.value = sumTree(node.left) + sumTree(node.right);
        return node.value + old_value;
    }
```